# Excel Shuts Down When Running a Macro

Tags: excel, vba

This VBA code works fine for approximately 5-6 loops. After that the Excel file shuts down. Sometimes, the Excel files recovers after the shutdown & sometimes it doesn't. Please help me fix this. I'm no VBA expert to fix this. Thanks.

```
Sub GetSpecificLinks()
'The code searches a website for the contact page url & pastes it in cell B2. 

'First define all the variables
Dim ie As Object 'Internet Explorer
Dim html As Object ' HTML document
Dim myLinks As Object ' Links collection
Dim myLink As Object 'Single Link
Dim result As String
Dim myURL As String 'Web Links on worksheet
Dim LastRow As Integer ' VBA execution should stop here

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'Loop through all the web links on the worksheet one by one and then do some things
For i = 2 To LastRow
    'Get the link from the worksheet and assign it to the variable
    myURL = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value
    'Now go to the website
    ie.navigate myURL
    'Keep the internet explorer visible
    ie.Visible = True
    'Ensure that the web page has downloaded completely
    While ie.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend
    'Get the data from the web page that is in the links and assign it to the variable
    result = ie.document.body.innerHTML
    'create a new html file
    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    'now place all the data extracted from the web page into the new html document
    html.body.innerHTML = result

    Set myLinks = html.getElementsByTagName("a")
    'loop through the collected links and get a specific link defined by the conditions
    For Each myLink In myLinks
        If myLink Like "*contact*" Or myLink Like "*nquiry*" Or myLink Like "*investor*" Or myLink Like "*relation*" Then
            Sheet1.Cells(i, "B").Value = myLink
        End If
        'go to the next link
    Next myLink
    'once the last web link on the sheet has been visited close the internet explorer
    If i = LastRow Then
        ie.Quit
    End If
    'go to the next web link on the worksheet
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Can't see anything that'd cause a crash, could be InternetExplorer, that isn't....great...could you do a WebRequest instead? Also, did you intend to overwrite the value in Column B for each link found?

Comment: Also, is this the only code you have in the whole workbook? Or do you also have other things in events like the change event?

Comment: @RyanWildry thanks for the feedback. I appreciate it. I've no idea how to do a WebRequest. Would you be willing to show me how? With regards to overwriting the value in Column B, I'm specifically looking for the Contact Page URL. Therefore, ideally, it should not overwrite. Thanks.

Comment: @braX this is the only code in the whole workbook. There is nothing else. Any help from your goodself is greatly appreciated. I'm not a coder so I don't understand much technical jargon. Sorry about that.

Comment: Easiest way if you have a newer version of excel is to use the WebService function. `Application.WorksheetFunction.WebService("www.google.com")` will do `GET` request at the URL you are requesting. This potentially could become `html.body.innerHTML = Application.WorksheetFunction.WebService("MYSITEGOESHERE")`. If you don't, look at XHR (WebRequests) requests, here's a guide I found online https://simpleexcelvba.com/how-to-get-http-request-with-xmlhttprequest/

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the issue, but you don't need to check for the last row to do the ie.quit. Remove that if statement and move the ie.Quit after the Next i.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @igittr It didn't solve the issue though. Excel still shuts down after 5-6 successful loops. I tried running it on a different laptop. There was no improvement. Excel still crashes. I've got a feeling that it's got something to do with the websites itself & not Excel...